# Почему файл app.config не попадает в папку Debug/Release при сборке проекта

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго времени суток!
Есть С# wpf проект в котором я использую файл app.config для хранения настроек.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>


  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CisDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=CISDbContextTest;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>


  <appSettings>
    <add key="httpAddress" value="http://10.17.224.85:810" />
    <add key="Regular" value="GetScheduleNormative4Place" />
    <add key="Operat" value="GetScheduleDynamic4Place" />
    <add key="Info" value="GetTrainInfo" />
    <add key="Stations" value="GetPlacesInfo" />
    <add key="Diagnost" value="SetStatusDevice" />

    <add key="User" value="ddd" />
    <add key="Password" value="1234" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Т.е. строка подключения к БД и настройки связи с удаленным сервером.

мне нужно чтобы пользователь мог открыть этот файл в блокноте и поменять данные, после загрузить программу и чтобы данные принялись из этого файл.

в режиме отладки все работает отлично, но после сборки проекта этот файл не попадает в папку Debug. 
Подскажите что нужно сделать чтобы этот файл был в папке после сборки проекта?

Добавляю скриншот с настройками фала
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

контекст подключения к бд создается так

```
public class CisDbContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
    public CisDbContext() : base("CisDbContext")  //имя в секции connectionStrings в файле app.config
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте в свойствах этого файла выставить `Copy to Output Directory`

Comment: После этого он попадает в папку, но настройки берутся не оттуда, т.е. я удалили строку подключения к БД. Запустил екзешник и программа подключилась к БД

Comment: А покажите ваш код, который идет в `app.config` и берет там данные

Comment: Вы используете `EF`?

Comment: string httpAdr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("httpAddress"); Да я использую EF

Comment: Файл конфига в папке Debug/Release будет иметь название appname.exe.config.

Comment: Это при текущих настройках app.config? У меня нет такого файла